# Issues while running Register-ELBInstanceWithLoadBalancer on powershell

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, aws-powershell

I am trying to add existing Windows Instances to and ELB using below command on powershell :-

> > Register-ELBInstanceWithLoadBalancer -LoadBalancerName ire798ELB
> >     -Instances i-2eb0a88d -Region us-east-1a

But it is giving me below error :-

> > Register-ELBInstanceWithLoadBalancer : A WebException with status
> >     ConnectFailure was thrown. At line:1 char:1
> >     + Register-ELBInstanceWithLoadBalancer -LoadBalancerName ire798ELB -Instances i-2e ...
> >     + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> >         + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Amazon.PowerShe...dBalancerCmdlet:RegisterELBInst...dBalancerCmdlet) 
> >     [Register-ELBInstanceWithLoadBalancer], InvalidOperationException
> >         + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>
> Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceException,Amazon.PowerShell.Cmdlets.ELB.RegisterELBInstanceW
>   ithLoadBalancerCmdlet

I tried searching on the net but could not find anything helpful. Can anyone here help me with this please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your -Region parameter isn't correct. 'us-east-1a' is an availability zone within the us-east-1 region.

Comment: Thanks Roberts!! that was the mistake!